# jQuery .load() with different language

Tags: jquery, locale

I'm using jQuery to load a file into one DIV:

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
   var page = $(this).attr("title");
   $('#content').load('content/'+ page+'.php'); 
});
```

Before loading, the page is displaying OTHER LANGUAGE -- it is done by

`setlocale(LC_ALL,'es_ES.UTF-8');`

After click ".menu", the page displays the desired page, however, the language is going back to English, not es_ES. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script at 'content/some_page.php' must also set locale.  I think you are only setting it at the initial page load.